# PHP with Bootstrap popover don't render buttons and forms

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, server-side-rendering, bootstrap-popover

Bootstrap popover doesn't show button and form tags. All the markup works fine, except for buttons and forms:

[image: Screenshot of the app and console]

```
echo '<div class="shopping-cart-summary">';
   echo '<div class="shopping-cart-total">';
      echo '<b>Razem: '.$total.'$</b>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<div class="summarize-buttons">';
      echo '<button class="btn btn-danger">Wyczyść</button>';
      echo '<a href="buy.php" class="btn btn-warning">Kup</a>';
   echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

`<a>` tag works, button doesn't. Unfortunately I need to have button there, so I can post the form.

I've already tried to move the content into separate, invisible div, and then pointing to it on creation of the popover:

```
$('#shoppingCart').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() { return $('#popover-content').html() }
});
```

It didn't work, the effect was the same.

It simply doesn't render those tags, without any error. The php code works just fine when put into `body` section.

Comment: I used modal instead of popover and everything worked fine. Still, if anyone knows why it didn't work with the popover, I'll be happy to hear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this myself and found this in the documentation.

Tooltips and popovers use a javascript sanitizer to prevent XSS.

Read through the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer) for instructions on whitelisting elements.